# log4j.properties specific level for clojure namespace

Tags: logging, clojure, log4j

How can I set the log level threshold for a clojure namespace?

I want to set a general filter to only let `WARN` messages through but `DEBUG` messages for my own code in the clojure namespace `reagent-project` and its sub namespaces, i.e. `reagent-project.routes`. The last line in the config has no effect:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, stdout

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{mm:ss} %-5p%c{1}:%L %m%n
log4j.logger.reagent_project=DEBUG, stdout
```

Comment: You should be using a -, not an _ in the ns name.